# Line chart not appearing correctly

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

I am uploading data from JSON to form a line chart. This is my JSON data

```
Morris.Line({
    element: 'morris-line-chart',
    data: [
      {y1: '23-07-15 01:12 AM - 23-07-15 02:04 AM', value: 9.8},
      {y1: '23-07-15 01:07 AM - 23-07-15 01:47 AM', value: 37.83},
      {y1: '23-07-15 12 AM - 23-07-15 01:13 AM', value: 18.12},
      {y1: '23-07-15 12 AM - 23-07-15 12:32 AM', value: 15.33},
      {y1: '22-07-15 11 PM - 23-07-15 12:10 AM', value: 13},
      {y1: '22-07-15 11 PM - 22-07-15 11:52 PM', value: 14.33},
      {y1: '22-07-15 11 PM - 22-07-15 11:35 PM', value: 27.83},
      {y1: '22-07-15 10 PM - 22-07-15 11:18 PM', value: 8.92},
      {y1: '22-07-15 10 PM - 22-07-15 10:47 PM', value: 9.12},
      {y1: '22-07-15 10 PM - 22-07-15 10:35 PM', value: 9.18},
      {y1: '22-07-15 10 PM - 22-07-15 10:22 PM', value: 7.85}

    ],
    xkey: 'y1',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    labels: ['Value']
  });
```

My HTML Code is

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Job Execution Trend
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="morris-line-chart"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
 </div>
```

But my graph is not coming up correctly. The X axis is only showing as year and Y axis is cluttering the data together.

Can someone help me on where I am going wrong ?

Here is the fiddle entry for same  http://www.bootply.com/gbVur25DT2

Comment: Can we have a demo in fiddle.

Comment: So we are supposed to 'guess' what your problem is since we don't see the actual code?

Comment: Please find the fiddle for same http://www.bootply.com/gbVur25DT2

Comment: Date format is incorrect it should be `23-07-2015` instead of `23-07-15`. But this is not solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more analysis and was able to fix it .

Need to make the time as false .

parseTime: false

Answer (score 0):

According to [morris.js docs](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) timestaps format in xkey should be:

- 2012
- 2012 Q1
- 2012 W1
- 2012-02
- 2012-02-24
- 2012-02-24 15:00
- 2012-02-24 15:00:00
- 2012-02-24 15:00:00.000

For example: `{y1: '2015-07-23 2:00', value: 9.8}` and so on. [Check it](http://www.bootply.com/JJuQ1v1SmU).